# While creating scratch orgs getting this error "DML operation Delete not allowed on List<AccountShare>"

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I am trying to create a scratch org. My codebase is having a class which is doing a dml on accountshare record. For deployment of this class we need to have account's OWD as private. (As well as of contact, case and opprotunity). So I made changes in Account **Account.object-meta.xml**. and made sharing model as private.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <compactLayoutAssignment>SYSTEM</compactLayoutAssignment>
    <enableFeeds>true</enableFeeds>
    <enableHistory>false</enableHistory>
    <recordTypeTrackFeedHistory>false</recordTypeTrackFeedHistory>
    <sharingModel>Private</sharingModel>
</CustomObject>
`
```

Same for case, opportunity and contact. But still while deploying I am getting this error

```
DML operation Delete not allowed on List<AccountShare>
```

I can comment the dml operations and deploy it.

After first deployment subsequent deployments works fine even with AccounShare Code uncommented.

How we can fix this problem without having to do any manual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@David Reeds answer might be most accurate. But will take some time to implement.  So I have a quick workaround.

First deploy only the objects using command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m CustomObject
```

After that you can deploy whole code.

you can create a .sh file like scratch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sfdx force:source:deploy -m CustomObject 
sleep 30s
sfdx force:source:push
```

Then you can call ./scratch.sh

Above solution will work if your objects don't have dependency to other metadata like object translations and vfpages.

If that is the case then you can a file with commented code keep it in a folder lets say commentedcode and create other folder uncommentedCode.

Then lets create a scratch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

mv src/app/main/default/classes/abc.cls uncommentedCode/
sleep 4s
mv commentedcode/abc.cls src/app/main/default/classes/
sleep 4s
sfdx force:source:deploy 

mv src/app/main/default/classes/abc.cls commentedcode/
sleep 4s
mv uncommentedCode/abc.cls src/app/main/default/classes/
sleep 4s

sfdx force:source:deploy -p src/app/main/default/classes/abc.cls
```

Again run scratch.sh

So what I am doing is first deploying code with commented accountshare dml's and once all the deployment is done of account as private record is done then deploying uncommented code.

I will accept this answer as correct for now. If anyone else have more correct solution.. please write your answer I will be happy to make your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing Settings changes take a non-zero amount of time to complete, and until they complete, the relevant Share object is not available.

If you're creating scratch orgs in a CI context, you'll need to implement a polling solution. Once you deploy your `CustomObject` metadata to the scratch org to enable sharing on those objects, have a script poll the Describe API until the required Share objects become available. Then proceed to deploy the remainder of your metadata.

If you're building one-off orgs, just wait a few minutes for the email that your sharing update is complete, or check in the org to see that it's finished, prior to performing your next deployment.